# Firefox contentEditable issue using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, contenteditable

I have an issue with the tag "contenteditable", only in firefox. I want an user to be able to modify the title of a survey he is creating, and the title of the questions which are dynamically created. It works well on IE and Chrome, but on Firefox I can't modify the question title.

Here is what it looks like 
on chrome : https://gyazo.com/f142c432fcd2994a5f254106d912ff11

and on firefox : https://gyazo.com/5e454710231dc5c957dc46358cf92cf0

The code for the title (which works perfectly fine) is

```
<h3 id="surveyTitle" class="text_justify fi-page-edit" contenteditable="true">Survey title</h3>
```

And for the generated questions

```
    var questionDiv = document.createElement("div");
    questionDiv.innerHTML = "<div class='large-12 columns mybold fi-page-edit' style='resize: none;' contenteditable='true' id='title"+questionNumber+"'>Question "+questionNumber+"</div>  </br>";
    var container = document.getElementById("viewForm");
    container.appendChild(questionDiv);
    container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
```

Maybe it's because "viewForm" is a disabled fieldset :

```
<form>
  <fieldset disabled="disabled" id="viewForm">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

But since it works on every other browser, I really don't see where is the problem...

Comment: Did you see any error in firebug

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi no, there is no error when i load the page nor when i click on the question title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it was actually because of the "disabled" tag. Firefox seems to be the only browser which doesn't allow "contentEditable" inside a "disabled" div so I removed it, and now I add it to each anwser input so that the question title is not disabled anymore. (i hope it's clear, sorry if it's not)